# Как в delphi xe 2 передать файл по сети любыми методами?

Tags: сеть, сокеты, delphi

Как в delphi xe 2 передать файл по сети любыми методами?

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](http://www.delphisources.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=13995)

Comment: Что значит "любыми методами"? В виде массива байтов? закодировано в base64? в транспортном потоке? Какие еще есть способы? И вот так просто взять и отправить?

Comment: @SoWa, человеку нужно, чтобы файл был передан с машины на машину. Очевидно, он не сильно осведомлен в существующих вариантах (или ему правда не важно).

Comment: любым способом - это значит - мне особо не играет роли. Лишь бы можно было большие файлы кидать. С тарых дельфах я брал исходники примеров на сокетах. В новой дельфе всё изменилось - не знаю как это сделать. Там и инди другие и iohandler  - если не сложно код примера, заранее спс

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/125736/как-отослать-большие-файлы  вот тут я уже и свой код рабочий на мелких файлах выложил

Answer (score 1):

используйте 
    `TIdTCPServer`
    и
    `TIdTCPClient`

Передача файла займет всего одну строчку вашего кода )))

```
TIdTCPClient.WriteFile
```

Пример есть демках.

Comment: тема получила развитие http://hashcode.ru/questions/125736/как-отослать-большие-файлы

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, я кода предоставить не смогу - Дельфи уже лет семь как не занимаюсь. Но мне кажется, что Вы просто не имеете под рукой привычных сокетов, с которыми умеете работать. В свое время в Delphi 7 я сталкивался с такой проблемой - нет сокетов. Но они дополнительно ставятся. Для вашей версии Delphi [вот так](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing_Socket_Components).